# Joomla K2 item image hover

Tags: image, video, joomla, hover, k2

Hy,

Is there a way to make hover on item image, but when is hover plays video?

Something like this but not in popup:
[Demo](http://www.shutterstock.com/video/category/Healthcare-7/?ref_context=sf_category_thumb)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box.
I'm sure this is a paid extension for this but if you would like to code it the good old fashioned way you can use jQuery and HTML5 video player to achieve this.

```
  <video id="video" width="420">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <a id="thumbnail">Im the thumbnail</a>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery('#thumbnail').hover(function() {
     jQuery('#video').show(); 
       jQuery('#video').play(); 
   }, function() {
          jQuery('#video').hide(); 
       jQuery('#video').pause(); 
   });
 }); 

</script>
```

What I suggest is linking the video and thumbnail either via a data-attribute:

e.g

```
<a id="thumbnail" data-video="#video"></a>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery('#thumbnail').hover(function() {
     jQuery(jQuery(this).data('video')).show(); 
       jQuery(jQuery(this).data('video')).play(); 
   }, function() {
          jQuery(jQuery(this).data('video')).hide(); 
       jQuery(jQuery(this).data('video')).pause(); 
   });
 }); 

</script>
```

on the thumbnail or making it relative to a parent container for multiple videos.